# Using Python to get a best fit from data

Tags: python, numpy, best-fit

New Python user ready to make my first simple code (hopefully!). My goal is to use some kind of best fit feature that Python has to take the make and amount of vehicles to find out what location this data most closely resembles.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import minimize
```

These are the three cities I have:

```
cities = ['Washington DC', 'Seattle', 'Miami']
```

These are the makes of the vehicles:

```
car_inputs = ['Ford', 'Chevy', 'Dodge']
```

Here are the values I have that I want to run in the code:

```
input_values = {'Ford': 124, 
            'Chevy': 34, 
            'Dodge': 77}
```

This is the database that stores my data from which I am trying to find a best fit for my input. Note, my input is identical to those of Washington DC.:

```
dealer_database = {'Washington DC': {'Ford': 124, 'Chevy': 34, 'Dodge': 77},
                   'Seattle': {'Ford': 500, 'Chevy': 80, 'Dodge': 58},
                   'Miami': {'Ford': 254, 'Chevy': 105, 'Dodge': 30}}
```

I think I am needing to use Ax = b where I am solving for x to approach this problem. From what I read online, I will need x to use for a chi-squared calculation. Below is what I found from another post on SO:

```
L = len(b)
fun = lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A,x)-b)
x1 = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
sol = minimize(fun, x1, method='SLSQP', constraints={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x})
sol = minimize(fun, np.zeros(l), method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=[(0.,None) for x in xrange(l)])

solution = sol['x']
```

Since my input is identical to Washington DC, I want my solution as:

```
 solution = ([ 1.0, 0., 0.]) #first number represents Washington DC.
```

I believe these are the correct steps from what I have learned/researched online, but I do not know how to put it into play. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to convert the sample code you found into a working example, i.e., what should A, x, and b look like?